# How to add Java file to Build Path Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have some .java files that I'd like to include in my build path to utilize some of the classes and such inside them. I've added them to the **/lib** folder but it doesn't allow me to call data types and methods and such from the .java files in my **app** project (in the .MainActivity). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add them to your project, alongside your other Java classes, in an appropriate directory based on their package name.

Comment: they don't have package names. can I just add my apps package name? or how would i go about just referencing them from a directory?

Comment: "can I just add my apps package name?" -- probably, then put the files in the same directory as your other Java classes with that package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is just to add the Java source code to your existing project, alongside your existing Java code.

In your case, the Java files do not have a `package` declaration. That's... not good. But, you can add one, then put the files in the appropriate directory for that package in your project. For example, you could use the `package` used by some of your existing classes, then put the files in the same directory as those classes.

If the Java files already had a `package`, you could create a directory tree off of your `java/` directory based on that `package`, then put the Java files in that directory.